# Request is redirected to no layout page for Sitecore root item

Tags: presentation

We are seeing a lot of these warnings in the CD logs. Can anyone suggest how to investigate the root cause?

```
06:23:02 WARN  Request is redirected to no layout page. Item:
sitecore://web/{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}?lang=en&ver=1 
Device: {FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3} 
(/sitecore/layout/Devices/Default)
```

Comment: Do you see any paths in your IIS logs that could reveal the desired page? Perhaps items without a layout are being requested like a page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Michael, it helped. It was the "Health Check" feature which was firing ping requests. Since it fires with the default hostname of the AppService, which we haven't added to the supported Sitecore hostnames in the config, it was ending in a layout not found page. Setting the LogFileAppender to “%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] %m%n” as per http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2015/08/25/improve-your-sitecore-log-with-realtime-output-and-calling-class/ also helped in establishing that it was a proper http request and not any built in Sitecore tasks which logging that warning.